# Does there exist a PID for each tomcat service? If so, then can we find the service name from that PID of the running tomcat service?

Tags: linux, services, tomcat

I am working on linux server.

I want to know whether there exists a PID for each tomcat service running on any server.

If a PID for a particular tomcat service exists, then can we find the service name corresponding to that PID?

Can we list all the tomcat services running on the server?

Comment: You tagged both Linux and ibm-unix-system-services; can you clarify the OS you're working in?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am working on linux server. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0):

ps -ef |grep tomcat

```
sun 5144 1 0 10:21 pts/1 00:00:06 /Java/jdk/bin/java
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/java/tomcat/common/endorsed -classpath :/java/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/java/tomcat/bin/commons-logging-api.jar
-Dcatalina.base=/java/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/java/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/java/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

PID=5144

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Actually when I am executing this command: ps -ef | grep tomcat. It is not showing anything. But there are some services in which instead of Dcatalina it is showing Dwapper and Djavax. Can you please tell me what is that? And how to find out those services from command line?

Comment: On the command line for any Java process, any options of the form `-Dproperty=value` are setting Java system property values. The actual Java class to be executed in this example is `org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap`. `catalina` is Tomcat's J2EE servlet container. Depending on where Tomcat is installed and how it's configured, the actual word `tomcat` may or may not appear on the server process's command line at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use netstat to capture the PID. But this will depend on whether or not the service is actually running on the server. netstat would capture the port it is binding to as well as the PID and program name. Granted that you have Tomocat running on port 80, you can try the following:

`netstat -tulnp | grep '80'`